# Exporting a table with header and subheader

Tags: beginner, file, matrix, matlab

I have an array matrix, for example A(3,3), I want to make a table with header names like, ['force','mass','acceleration'], the second row contains the units (subheader), ['N','Kg','m/s^2'], and the rest of the table contains the elements of A.

I want to export this table as a (.dat) file, how can I do that in an efficient way (I want to implement it for a large number of matrices)?

This is my code, which I believe it is not professional.

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6];

C(1,:) = {'force','mass','acceleration'};
C(2,:) = {'N','Kg','m/s^2'};

C(3,:) = num2cell(A(1,:));
C(4,:) = num2cell(A(2,:));
T = cell2table(C)

writetable(T,'tabledata.dat')
```

also this is a new update

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
C(1,:) = {'N','Kg','m/s^2'};
C(3:5,:) = num2cell(A(:,:));

T = cell2table(C)

T.Properties.VariableNames = {'force' 'mass' 'acceleration'};

writetable(T,'tabledata.dat','Delimiter','\t')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming the data in variable `A` is calculated somehow in MATLAB, and that you have a matrix `A` that you want on a tab-delimited format, with headers. If that's the case, then `writetable` is probably your best bet (as you have figured out).

The expressions below are very hard to scale, since 100 rows of data results in 100 rows of code.

```
C(3,:) = num2cell(A(1,:));
C(4,:) = num2cell(A(2,:));
```

Simply doing `data_in_cells = num2cell(A)` is much more robust and clean.

The following is probably the best way to achieve what you want:

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6];

headers = {'force', 'mass', 'acceleration'};
units = {{'N'},{'Kg'},{'m/s^2'}};   % or: units = num2cell(units);  

table_of_data = cell2table([units; num2cell(A)]);
table_of_data.Properties.VariableNames = headers;

writetable(table_of_data,'tabledata.dat','Delimiter','\t')
```

The reason why I use a double nested cell for `units` is that when trying to create the matrix MATLAB checks if all elements in each column are of the same type, and if so concatenates them as that type. In MATLAB, `[65 66, 'C']` becomes `ABC`, because it converts the entire array to chars. 
Since the first column contains a single character `N`, this column looks like:

```
'N'
1
4
```

MATLAB translates this to: `char([78; 1; 4])`. `1` and `4` when converted to [ASCII-characters](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) becomes: "Start of heading", and "End of transmission". These are not printable ASCII. Placing `N` inside a cell will result in the correct result, since MATLAB can't concatenate a cell and integers.

Note that I'm not placing `headers`, `units` and the data in a single cell as you did (`C`). This is because:

1. You don't need that cell anywhere
2. Avoid the additional memory overhead